# net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND but little different

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am just learning JS and was trying to change the background image of the selected div block. But it gave me following error in the browser console:

> net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Here I am trying to change the background image of the 'image' div via a JS function using 'this' keyword. The image URL is perfectly correct. I have checked it in the browser. I don't know what to do.

```js
function upDate(previewPic) {
  document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url('previewPic.src')";
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="image">Hover over an image below to display here.</div>
<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" />
</html>
```

When I am doing this, there's is no error:

```
<script>
function upDate(previewPic) {
    console.log(previewPic.src);
}
</script>
```

This shows that it is reading the link but not when I'm using it.
I have no idea what to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`previewPic.src` which you are passing as an argument in the URL is not actually the real image source is just string so that replace it with the real source like the following

### Example

```js
function upDate(previewPic) {
  document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cdn-prod.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/322/322868/golden-retriever-puppy.jpg')";
}
```

```css
#image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">Hover over an image below to display here.</div>

<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" />
```

or if you want the same image as the one you're hovering just do the following

```js
function upDate(previewPic) {
  document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = `url('${previewPic.src}')`;
}
```

```css
#image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">Hover over an image below to display here.</div>

<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" />
```